# Manually installing a module in pythonanywhere and changing it's location

Tags: python, pip, yaml, pythonanywhere, ruamel.yaml

EDIT: So, after installing Ruamel.yaml from a local path, uninstalling it and reinstalling it worked perfectly. I have no idea why re-installing it changed anything, but hey, it works.

Please close this question.

Original:

> I wanted to install the [Ruamel.Yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) module for *Python3.4* in
>   *PythonAnywhere*. However,if I tried to use **PIP3.4** I used to get the following result:
>
> ```
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ruamel.yaml (from versions: )
> No matching distribution found for ruamel.yaml
> ```
>
> Trying to work around that, I downloaded *ruamel.yaml-0.11.6.tar.gz*
>   ([the file tagged as Source](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml)), and install it with **PIP3.4** using
>   the **-e** flag. Apparently, **PIP3.4** told me it was a success, and
>   trying to re-install the package gives me the following message:
>
> ```
> pip3.4 install --user ruamel.yaml
> Requirement already satisfied (use--upgrade to upgrade): ruamel.yaml
> in /home/<username>/dumpfolder_version3/ruamel.yaml-0.11.6
> ```
>
> However, when I try to run the library I get the following error...
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):        
> File "/home/<username>/mailgun/configurar_menu.py", line 3, in <module>
> import ruamel.yaml as yaml
> ImportError: No module named 'ruamel'
> ```
>
> Do you have any idea what could be the problem?
>
> If I try to reinstall another package python already has, I get this
>   message
>
> ```
> pip3.4 install --user pyyaml
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyyaml
> in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
> ```
>
> Could that difference be the problem?

Comment: As a tip: If the question was solved, you can either delete or self-answer it

Comment: Can you confirm that when you reinstalled you did not use `install -e`?

Comment: Yes, when I re-installed I did not use the **-e** flag. For some unknown reason, it worked this time (remember, I tried it before and it didn't use tow ork). May have been a *PythonAnywhere* PIP issue.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a number of problems, but unfortunately I don't have access to pythonanywhere so I cannot test them out. I do however have some experience with `ruamel.yaml` and its installation ¹.

The main problem is that you try to install in editable mode, but `ruamel` is a namespace and `pip install -e` cannot properly handle that. Unfortunately `ruamel.yaml`'s `setup.py` currently doesn't catch that (it does if you try to use `python setup.py` to install), and because of that doesn't warn or correct its behaviour.

Your site-packages directory is probably already messed up so that `pip` is incapable of restoring, but you can try `pip uninstall -y ruamel.yaml`. After that check if everything starting with `ruamel` is removed from your `lib/python3.4/site-packages` directory and reinstall with `pip install ruamel.yaml*tar.gz`. The latter is also what you need to do if you start from scratch.

After correct installation on 3.4 you should have the following if you do `tree ruamel*` in your `site-packages` directory:

```
ruamel
└── yaml
    ├── comments.py
    ├── compat.py
    ├── composer.py
    ├── configobjwalker.py
    ├── constructor.py
    ├── cyaml.py
    ├── dumper.py
    ├── emitter.py
    ├── error.py
    ├── events.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── loader.py
    ├── main.py
    ├── nodes.py
    ├── parser_.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── comments.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── compat.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── composer.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── configobjwalker.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── constructor.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── cyaml.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── dumper.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── emitter.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── error.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── events.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── loader.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── main.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── nodes.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── parser_.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── reader.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── representer.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── resolver.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── scalarstring.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── scanner.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── serializer.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── tokens.cpython-34.pyc
    │   └── util.cpython-34.pyc
    ├── reader.py
    ├── representer.py
    ├── resolver.py
    ├── scalarstring.py
    ├── scanner.py
    ├── serializer.py
    ├── tokens.py
    └── util.py
ruamel.yaml-0.11.6.dist-info
├── DESCRIPTION.rst
├── INSTALLER
├── METADATA
├── metadata.json
├── namespace_packages.txt
├── RECORD
├── top_level.txt
└── WHEEL
```

---

¹ <sub>I am the author</sub>

Comment: After uninstalling ruamel.yaml (using the code above) I was able to **pip3.4 install --user ruamel.yaml**. I have no idea why it didn't work before, I know very little of Python's package-managment, but it worked perfectly this time. Thanks for the help. It's great to see an author caring so much about his software. :)

Answer (score 0):

As edited above, this was already solved. According to Yamuel's own author, it may have been because the **-e** flag was messing everything up.